# Cannot get content from a website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web

I want to use python to get content from [this website](https://www.itslaw.com/detail?judgementId=29124888-491d-47ce-a88f-af9ccf003f7c&area=1&index=1&sortType=1&count=5369531&conditions=searchWord%2B%E5%80%9F%E8%B4%B7%2B1%2B%E5%80%9F%E8%B4%B7).
The page looks like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiohR.png)

But when I saw the source code or read the page with python, it looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z9c4.png)

All the pages are the same.

my python codes below:

```
req=urllib.request.Request(url,headers=headers)
response=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
`content=response.read()`
`print(content.get_text())`
```

Please help me...
soup=BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')

Comment: It looks like you're only looking at the <head> portion of the HTML response.  Are you sure the portion you're expecting is not down in the <body>?

Comment: Thank you for your answer!I did search threw the <body>,Inspecting element will see the portion;Viewing source code cann;t see the portion;my python codes also cann't see the portion.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, re

def remove_some_special_tags(raw_html_data):

    scripts = re.compile(r'<(script).*?</\1>(?s)')
    css = re.compile(r'<style.*?/style>')
    comments = re.compile(r"<!--(.|\s|\n)*?-->")

    text = scripts.sub('', raw_html_data.lstrip("<!doctype html>"))
    text = css.sub('', text)
    text = comments.sub('', text)

    return text

url = "https://www.itslaw.com/detail?judgementId=29124888-491d-47ce-a88f-af9ccf003f7c&area=1&index=1&sortType=1&count=5369531&conditions=searchWord%2B%E5%80%9F%E8%B4%B7%2B1%2B%E5%80%9F%E8%B4%B7."
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
raw_data = str(response.content, encoding="utf-8")

html_beauty = remove_some_special_tags(raw_data)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_beauty, 'lxml')
all_text = ''.join(soup.findAll(text=True)).replace("\n\n", "\n")


print(all_text)
```

Good Luck ...

Comment: Thanks! But this code also cann't get the content I want.